# Is it possible to have dp iniated SSO and sp Initated SSO can co exist in spring saml web app?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am having a spring SAML application where user will be initiated from the idp at the first time login and during manager override screen, sp will initiate the sso request for the manager to idp. During this situation, the browser will store two idp cookie session of base user and his manager, Or manager's sso idp cookie session will override the existing base user sso cookie session?

Both user uses the same idp provider (ex:Okta)

i have searched a lot over the internet and nothing gives an answer.

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

Typically so called 'session cookies' are stored in the browser's memory and send to the 'server'. If the 'server' sees this cookie, it consideres the user to be authenticated and does not prompt for further authentication. If the 'base user' and the 'manager' use the same browser, the 'manager' will not be propmpted for authentication.
This standard behavior can only be changed, when the attribute `ForceAuthn` is set to `true` in the SAML AuthnRequest sent in SP-initiated SSO flow, the IdP must always prompt for authentication.